# Password Protected Directory intermittent fail

Tags: passwords, cpanel

I have a form on the only page within a directory that is password protected via cPanel. Such as...

www.site.com/directory/subdirectory/form.php

Once every twenty submits of the form (in the same session) I am redirected to:

www.site.com

and obviously the php form processing doesn't occur.

WHAT IS HAPPENING?

I have checked my redirects in cpanel and none are set. So I don-t even know why it goes to the index page!

NOTES
No question on SO mentions this problem and I have found nothing suitable in google. I'm not sure what the problem is so it's hard to 'google'.

Here is the form.php format

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  
session_start();
require 'functions.php';
connect();

/*“Æ” because  UTF-8 encoding without BOM looks like ANSI*/


if(isset($_POST['newJob'])){
      $jTDjobToDo = $_POST['jobToDo'];
    $jTDwhenInfo = $_POST['whenInfo'];
    $jTDwhenInfo = $jTDwhenInfo+ time();


            $jTDinsertNewJob = $conn ->prepare ("INSERT INTO jobstodo (jobToDo,whenInfo) VALUES(:jobToDo,:whenInfo)");
            $jTDinsertNewJob->bindParam(':jobToDo', $jTDjobToDo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $jTDinsertNewJob->bindParam(':whenInfo', $jTDwhenInfo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $jTDinsertNewJob->execute();
            echo "New job added!<br/>";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>My page</title>
        <LINK href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="newjobform">
ADD A NEW JOB
<form  action="http://www.site.com/myPage.php" method="POST">
New Job To Do <input type="text" name="jobToDo" id="newJobToDo" ><br/>

When to do<br/>
<input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="0" CHECKED>Now / 
<input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="86400"> 1 day
/ <input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="172800"> 2 days
/ <input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="345600">4 days<br/>
<input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="604800">7 days
/ <input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="1209600">14 days
/ <input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="2073600">24 days
/ <input type="radio" name="whenInfo" value="3888000">45 days<br/>


<input type="submit" value="ADD" name="newJob"><br/>
</form>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

The function php connects as so..

```
try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
//echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your php script? Are you doing any checking (sesion, post data, etc etc) that if it failed, might redirect to the home page?

Comment: @mituw done, i included the connect call too, for the PDO. Let me know  if I can add anything else.

Comment: Is there anything in `functions.php` that would be doing a check / redirect?

Comment: @mituw, the functions code is in the second part of the php code, with the pdo connect